# Angular Flex-Layout MediaObserver priority of the MediaChange

Tags: angular, flexbox, media

How can I get the current change of the MediaChange[] when I observing media changes via MediaObserver?

I observed the current is the first item in the array MediaChange[], I can use the the first item. Bu I also observed, in the MediaChange has a priority I also observed the current change had a highest priority  . Which can be the best?

Working code example:

```
  constructor(mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {
    this.mediaObserverAsObservable = mediaObserver.asObservable().subscribe((changes: MediaChange[]) => {
      // option A.
      const currentMediaChange = changes[0];
      if (currentMediaChange.mqAlias === 'sm' || currentMediaChange.mqAlias === 'xs') {
        if (this.sidenav) {
          this.sidenav.close();
        }
      } else {
        if (this.sidenav) {
          this.sidenav.open();
        }
      }
      
      // Option B.
      const maxPriority = changes.reduce(
        (currentMax, mediaChange) => (mediaChange.priority > currentMax ? mediaChange.priority : currentMax),
        changes[0].priority
      );
      const currentMediaChange = changes.find(mc => mc.priority === maxPriority);
      if (currentMediaChange) {
        if (currentMediaChange.mqAlias === 'sm' || currentMediaChange.mqAlias === 'xs') {
          if (this.sidenav) {
            this.sidenav.close();
          }
        } else {
          if (this.sidenav) {
            this.sidenav.open();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Or I can use mediaObserver.isActive() to identify what query matched for the current viewport?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [7.0.0-beta.24 (2019-03-17)](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/7e7912c1ef1a770d164523fae41cc4c569f33259/CHANGELOG.md#700-beta24-2019-03-17) the `angular/flex-layout` did a break change so `mediaObserver.asObservable()` is an observable that return  `MediaChange[]`

The [`MediaChange` source code](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/c45f2ae0b44ab8f29a4ff9bb858c5cf3d0aae71f/src/lib/core/media-change.ts#L22) has an attribute called priority which give you the priority of activation where looks like on `MediaChange[]` is sort by [descendent order](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/2ca78488aac8cd34b2839333f6058030f7ab075d/src/lib/core/media-trigger/media-trigger.ts#L115).

In other words highest priority is first. The option A I think so it's the best option based on above. Because you should choose the active `mediaQuery` and it's the most high priority. It's not needed use `reduce` when we know it's on first place.